# How to connect redis database in python

Tags: python, database, redis

I wrote a Python program. I want to use a high-speed database in it, and my choice is Radis. Please help me how to connect to this database in the Python program?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.